# How to avoid having a Window smaller than the minimum size of a UserControl in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, size, resize

I have an usercontrol (a statusbar) that has an implicit minimum size (not set via the property, what I mean is that when  it reaches a minimum size it can not be reduced and it's cropped).

Is there a way to let the main window know that the UserControl will being to be cropped and don't allow it to reduce its size? With such a smart layout system as WPF has it must be a way that it knows that it's cropping things. Look at the next image:

[image]

Comment: What type of layout container are you using (flow, etc)?

Comment: I'm actually using a stackpanel but i can use whatever I need to achieve my goals.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on your problem?

Comment: Not at all. Honestly, I find this very frustanting as this looks pretty obvious to me. Please, come back if you succeed.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Did this ever get resolved?

Comment: @denver: Nope, sorry :S

Answer (score 20):

Include **`MinHeight="MinSize" MinWidth="MinSize"`** inside the **`<Window>`** section

MinSize = Desired Integer Value ex 400/350 etc.

```
<Window x:Class="IOTA_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    MinHeight="400" MinWidth="650">
```

Comment: MinSize is not a fixed value, it depends on the DPI settings, font size settings, etc, so as far as I know this is not a valid solution. Anyway thanks for trying.

Comment: MinSize mean the desired size as I explained in the example

Comment: I got it but in WPF what you see on the screen depends on various settings, even with a fixed size, like DPI, font size, etc. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748828(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that's just what I'm asking in the question dude ;)

Answer (score 15):

This is how I solved it.  The solution is specific to my problem, but can be altered to get a variety of desired resizing behaviors.

First set the window so that it initially sizes itself to fit its contents.

```
<Window ...
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
```

Next I set each embedded control so that it reports a desired width and height.  Most built in controls do this for you.  You can do it for custom controls by overriding MeasureOverride or you can just set a width and height for the control.  Make this the minimum size you want the control to get.

```
<MyControl Name="_MyControlName" Width="640" Height="480" />
```

Don't worry about these 'hard' coded values effecting the behavior of the control.  We deal with that next.  Now when the window is displayed it will automatically adjust itself to fit your controls.

Next subscribe to the window loaded event.

```
<Window ...
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
```

In the window loaded event you can adjust the sizing behavior of your window and the controls in it.  You can make it so your controls can resize.  You can set a minimum size for the window to the size you just had layed out.  The advantage here is that you just allowed the layout system to find a good layout for you.  You want to leverage its work.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We know longer need to size to the contents.
        ClearValue(SizeToContentProperty);
        // We want our control to shrink/expand with the window.
        _MyControlName.ClearValue(WidthProperty);
        _MyControlName.ClearValue(HeightProperty);
        // Don't want our window to be able to get any smaller than this.
        SetValue(MinWidthProperty, this.Width);
        SetValue(MinHeightProperty, this.Height);
    }
```

What you place in the Window_Loaded method will depend on the behavior you are trying to accomplish.

Hope this can help some others save time.

Comment: Mmmm ... my concern here is that you are basing your initial layout on fixed sizes which may be wrong and lead to a wrong initial layout. How would you deal with that then?

Comment: That could be a problem. It hasn't however been for me. The built in controls (labels, buttons, etc) generally do a good job of reporting accurate size, and our custom controls do as well (by overriding MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride). For ones that do a poor job you can set a decent width/height in the XAML or even calculate it based on what data the control will be displaying ahead of time - then set via code behind or data binding. In the example I used I had a video control that did a poor job at this, so I set size to match the video stream (640x480) prior to displaying.

Comment: Hello again, I was in fact talking about things like different DPI settings, different text size settings, the kind of things that can make fixed sizes problematic, Have you tried the app with a different DPI?

Comment: You might occasionally need to take that into account.  In practice for me it has not been an issue.  When WPF does its 'size to contents' it will take those into account for you.  Usually custom style controls are build upon other components, many of which already take that into account.  If you really need a fixed number of physical pixels you might need to provide a calculated size, but in general the size specified in device independent units does the job for you.

Comment: You actually don't need to (nor should you) do this in the Loaded event.  Just override the form's MeasureOverride and set the min values there based on the will-be-returned desired size. Same effect, but that properly handles changes to children that would otherwise affect it since it's run on every measure, not just the initial one.  Also, clamp their values with Math.Ceiling. Works like a charm on any DPI setting.

Comment: Side-note: I wrote a custom ContentPresenter which overrides its own MeasureOverride and while it still measures all of its children, it always returns 0,0 (I call it a CrushablePresenter since it 'crushes' that control's layout measuring.)  I then place controls in it which I *don't* want to affect the minimum size (i.e. long lines of text, etc.) of the form from my prior comment. There's a little more to it than just that for things like text trimming, etc., but I'll leave that up to the reader to dig into.

Comment: This was very helpful, but I had to tweak it. I'm using this in a modal dialog that's opened by a modal dialog. 
Doing it in `Loaded` seems to prevent `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` from working. If I do it in `ContentRendered` instead I get the correct window placement, and the minimum size stuff still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the controls MinHeight property to prevent it getting smaller that desired.

Comment: I tried that and it's not working :( Anyway I think that the layout system must know that it's cropping an usercontrol and then must be a way without setting fixed values at code that makes maintenance harder.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm a little late but I would tell that I've found nearly the cleanest solution for this issue.

1.) Create a custom UserControl (if you are using any)

```
public class ExtendedUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent
    = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "ContentChanged",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(ExtendedUserControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this));
    }
}
```

2.) Attach the event to your UserControl

```
<extended:ExtendedUserControl Height="auto" Width="auto" cal:View.Model="{Binding CurrentModel}" ContentChanged="ExtendedUserControl_ContentChanged"/>
```

3.) **UPDATED** Now we come to the last part of the solution.

```
private void ExtendedUserControl_ContentChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread task = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                MinHeight = Height;
                MinWidth = Width;
            });
        });
        task.Start();
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm not working with WPF anymore but I remember there was something like Rendered event. You could check that.

Comment: Just checked this and I could not find any event for a UserControl or the control itself. Also I'm using MVVM and as far as I can tell the views are loaded before the bindings are created. Also it seems that I've had only some xaml bug since I'm able to remove the thread sleep now without any issues so far

Answer (score 0):

Can you put items in a Grid with Rows containing the constituent parts?

All items that must have a minimum height can go in rows with a similar minimum height.

Add the minimum heights up = Window.MinHeight.  Thus the window can never be smaller than the collective minimum heights of the necessary rows, so those rows should always display.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember reading somewhere (I may be wrong) that stack panels have borders based on infinity, and cannot handle such sizing issues.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

DockPanel vs StackPanel

Although DockPanel can also "stack" child elements, DockPanel and StackPanel do not produce analogous results in some usage scenarios. For example, the order of child elements can affect their size in a DockPanel but not in a StackPanel. This is because **StackPanel measures in the direction of stacking at PositiveInfinity, whereas DockPanel measures only the available size.**

There's a section of the post where it talks about nested panels too. Which might be what you need.

Or maybe use a grid with the status in the bottom row?