# Is it possible to force a window to never size below the desired size for its children?

Tags: wpf, layout, minimum-size

I know for a `Window` (any `FrameworkElement` actually) you can specify a `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`.  What I'm wondering is how I can make that minimum match the window's `DesiredSize`?

In other words, I want to say *'You can resize this window as small as you want, but not smaller than the minimum needed to show its content.'*

For instance, say I have a simple `Window` containing a `DockPanel` with three items in it arranged vertically.  For simplicity, we'll only talk about the height.

1. The first is a `Rectangle` with a `Height` of 20 and is pinned to the top so its `DesiredSize.Height` is 20.
2. The second is a `Label` which has a `MinHeight` of 20 and is pinned to the bottom, but can grow in height if there are multiple lines of text. (Currently, there's only a single word so the `DesiredSize.Height` is also 20)
3. The third item is a custom `ImageViewer` control that fills the remaining area in the middle, but which will never be smaller than its content, plus its padding.  Currently the image is 15x15 and the padding is 2.5 on a side so its `DesiredSize.Height` is 20 (2.5 + 15 + 2.5)

With the above, the `DesiredSize.Height` for the StackPanel would thus be 60 (20 + 20 + 20), and the `DesiredSize.Height` of the `Window` would be that 60 + it's own chrome's height (let's just say that too is 20), and that seems to give me a `Window.DesiredSize.Height` of 80.  That's what I'm after for the MinHeight of the window.

I've tried binding The `Window`'s `MinHeight` to its `DesiredSize.Height` via a `SizeToDoubleConverter` (that takes a `Dimension` to determine to return the `Width` or `Height` accordingly) but it didn't have any effect.

This looks promising...

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {

    var desiredSize = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

    MinWidth  = Math.Ceiling(DesiredSize.Width);
    MinHeight = Math.Ceiling(DesiredSize.Height);

    return desiredSize;
}
```

*Note: I tend to use `Math.Ceiling` on the actual `DesiredSize.Height` because it's usually a fraction and the layout will get thrown off when aligning to device pixels, messing things up.*

The above is close to working, but you run into issues if you want to also set the `MaxHeight` equal to it (for instance, to allow horizontal, but not vertical sizing.)

This kind of thing is easy with AutoLayout in iOS/macOS, but I'm not sure how to do this in WPF, even programmatically.  I just have to keep guessing at what size looks best.

Comment: So what's the problem with setting the `MinHeight` to `60` (or `StackPanel.ActualHeight`). Or handle the `SizeChanged` event?

Comment: You might be able to get away with using the trick shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407415/1177147).

Comment: @mm8, how could I know what that number is without walking the tree?  That's my entire point.

Comment: The entire tree? A window has a `Content` property. And a `UIElement` has an `ActualHeight` property. Or what height do you want?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear.  I'm essentially trying to lock the window's `MinWidth` to `DesiredSize.Width` and `MinHeight` to `DesiredSize.Height` so the window will never be smaller than the smallest valid content it can have.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. I've achieved the goal but it's not pretty. I wouldn't recommend this approach but it does what it says on the tin.

Bare bones, project called DynamicMinumumSize:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new BackingData();
    }
}

public class BackingData
{
    public double StackMinHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicMinimumSize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicMinimumSize"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:BackingData}" MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=Stack, Path=MinHeight}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ChildMinHeightConverter x:Key="ChildMinHeightConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Stack">
        <StackPanel.MinHeight>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ChildMinHeightConverter}" >
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="StackMinHeight" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </StackPanel.MinHeight>
        <Button MinHeight="53">Min Height 53</Button>
        <Button MinHeight="53">Min Height 53</Button>
        <Button MinHeight="53">Min Height 53</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Converter:

```
public class ChildMinHeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var currentMinHeight = values[0] as double? ?? 0;

        if (values[1] is Panel)
        {
            var parent = values[1] as Panel;
            foreach (var child in parent.Children)
            {
                //Hack: The children won't necessarily be buttons
                currentMinHeight += (child as Button).MinHeight;
            }
        }
        //HACK: +40, I think it's the window toolbar.....
        return currentMinHeight + 40;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Visualised:

[image]